# What is the method of solving these types of exponential equations

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I've seem to come to a sort of a road block while doing my homework, the following questions are very similar to this one so any insight in how to solve these types of equations would be of much help.
$(x-2)^{x^2-x}=(x-2)^{12}$

Comment: Apply a logarithm function for both sides.

Comment: $x=2$ is a solution; let $x \not =2$, divide, you get $(x-2)^{x^2-x-12}=1$; and now?

Answer (score 1):

You want solutions to
$(x-2)^{x^2-x}=(x-2)^{12}
$.

If $x = 2$
this is true,
so that is a solution.

If
$x \ne 2$,
you can,
as suggested by Peter Szilas,
divide by
$(x-2)^{12}$
to get
$1
=(x-2)^{x^2-x-12}
$.

For this to be true
we must have either
$x-2=1$ or $-1$, so that
$x = 3$ or $1$
(this works since
both exponents are even),
or
$x^2-x-12 = 0$,
so that,
since
$x^2-x-12 = (x-4)(x+3)$,
$x = 4$
or $x = -3$.

Therefore the solutions are
$x = 1, 2, 3, 4, -3$.

Comment: When $x=2$ the exponents are not zero.

Comment: OOps! You are correct.